# Line chart with arrows using Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to create a Chart.js line chart with an arrow at the end of a line. The arrow should point in the same direction as the line, i.e., the rightmost portion of the line should look like a ray instead of a line segment.

I tried using the point configuration options to change the rightmost data point's `pointStyle` from a `'circle'` to a `'triangle'`, and then rotating the triangle to point in the same direction as the line to look like an arrow. However, in order to dynamically calculate the rotation degrees, I needed to know the chart's y-axis range (automatically calculated by Chart.js), and I ran into difficulties when trying to get that value from Chart.js.

Does anyone know a good way to put an arrow on a line in a Chart.js line chart? Info on how to reliably ascertain the y-axis range would help too.

Edit: Here's a JSFiddle with the solution that I tried out: https://jsfiddle.net/x6rnysvf/1/

Comment: can you share minimal reproducible code here so that we can help better?

Comment: Just added a JSFiddle

Comment: I have not found a better solution myself.